# Lockscreen icon for my wp7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to set

```
<DeviceLockImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\LockImage.png</DeviceLockImageURI>
```

in my `WMAppManifest.xml` but I cant seem to figure out where it should be. Am I not allowed on Windows Phone 7 to add a lockscreen icon?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsphone/2009/deployment" AppPlatformVersion="7.1">
  <App xmlns="" ProductID="{c4fd8893-4bf8-4513-993a-459b70ffa216}" Title="PivotApp1" RuntimeType="Silverlight" Version="1.0.0.0" Genre="apps.normal"  Author="PivotApp1 author" Description="Sample description" Publisher="PivotApp1">
    <IconPath IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">ApplicationIcon.png</IconPath>
    <Capabilities>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_GAMERSERVICES"/>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE"/>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER"/>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_LOCATION"/>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB"/>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MICROPHONE"/>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING"/>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER"/>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION"/>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_SENSORS"/>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT"/>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA"/>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_CONTACTS"/>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_APPOINTMENTS"/>
    </Capabilities>
    <Tasks>
      <DefaultTask  Name ="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml"/>
    </Tasks>
    <Tokens>
      <PrimaryToken TokenID="PivotApp1Token" TaskName="_default">
        <TemplateType5>
          <BackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Background.png</BackgroundImageURI>
          <Count>0</Count>
          <Title>PivotApp1</Title>
        </TemplateType5>
      </PrimaryToken>
    </Tokens>
  </App>
</Deployment>
```

Comment: I don't think you can use lockscreen icon on wp7. It's only available on wp8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 apps cannot interact with the lockscreen, that is way you cannot set the icon in a Windows Phone 7 project. Only Windows Phone 8 apps can do that.